# need to create lightning component to take input Name from user and create Account record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

I am new to Lightning. My requirement is to take input(name) in form and after clicking the submit button, the record(Account) have to create with the name.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I have created a sample of code as per your requirement :-

first create a lightning component`

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="AccountController"
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>
<aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Account"
     default="{ 'sobjectType': 'ExpenseAccountc',
                     'Name': '',
                   }"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<div>
    <form>
    </div>

          <ui:inputText aura:id="AccountName" label="New Account Name"
                        class="slds-input"
                        labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                        value="{!v.newAccount.Name}"
                        required="true"/>
         </div>
    <ui:button label="Submit" 
                       class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                       labelClass="label"
                       press="{!c.createAccount}"/>
              <ui:button label="Cancel" 
                       class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                       labelClass="label"
                       press="{!c.Close}"/>
           </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

client side controller for this component

```
createAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
    var newAcc = component.get("v.newAccount");
    var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");
    action.setParams({ 
        "acc": newAcc
    });
    if (callback) {
      action.setCallback(this, callback);
    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action)
}
```

Now create a server side controller for insert account record on the Salesforce.`

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account saveAccount (Account acc) {

    upsert acc;
    return acc;
    }
}
```

`

Thanks,
Piyush Kumar

Comment: I am not able to post correctly. I created a google doc please go to this:- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sfunOwtdmSc7rPHT2xvC_okMiUr26gdm9zyHf84y3Aw/edit#

Comment: thanks Piyush for quick response.but i am getting error after running the application. "Something has gone wrong. action is undefined. Please try again."

Comment: follow this link for help to create form in salesforce lightning :-https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/qs_aotp_app.htm

Comment: Hello Ajay i have modified the document please follow up. I created a account through this modified  code in my org https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sfunOwtdmSc7rPHT2xvC_okMiUr26gdm9zyHf84y3Aw/edit#

Comment: this error was occurs because of little mistake on component

Comment: How to do the same for a List Custom Setting instead of Account object?

Answer (score 1):

Here I have created a sample of code as per your requirement :-

first create a lightning component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="AccountController">
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>`<aura:attribute name="newAccount" type="Account"
     default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Account',
                     'Name': '',
                   }"/>
<div>
<form>
      <ui:inputText aura:id="AccountName" label="New Account Name"
                    class="slds-input"
                    labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                    value="{!v.newAccount.Name}"
                    required="true"/>

<ui:button label="Submit" 
                   class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                   labelClass="label"
                   press="{!c.createAccount}"/>
          <ui:button label="Cancel" 
                   class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                   labelClass="label" press="{!c.Close}"/>
</form>
```

client side controller for this component

```
 ({
  createAccount : function(component, event) {
    var newAcc = component.get("v.newAccount");
    var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");
    action.setParams({ 
        "acc": newAcc
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
           var state = a.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var name = a.getReturnValue();
               alert("hello from here"+name);
            }
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action)
}
```

})
Now create a server side controller for insert account record on the Salesforce.

```
public with sharing class AccountController{
    @AuraEnabled

    public static Account saveAccount (Account acc) {

    upsert acc;
    return acc;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Piyush Kumar

Answer (score -1):

```
<aura:component controller="AccountController1">
    
    
   <aura:attribute name="createAcc" type="Account" default="{'sObjectType' : 'Account','Name' : ''}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objName" type="String" default="Account"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fldName" type="String" default="Rating"/>
   
    
   <aura:attribute type="Account[]" name="acctList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
      
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAcc}"/>
    <div class="slds-p-around_small">
        <lightning:input type="Text" label="Name" value="{!v.createAcc.Name}"/>
        <lightning:input type="Text" label="Account Number" value="{!v.createAcc.AccountNumber}"/>
        <lightning:input type="Email" name="email2" value="{!v.createAcc.Email}" label="Email ID"/>
        <lightning:input type="Phone" label="Phone Number" value="{!v.createAcc.Phone}"/>
        <lightning:select label="Rating" value="{!v.createAcc.Rating}">
            <option value="">—None—</option>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.ratingList}" var="ac">
                <option value="{!ac}">{!ac}</option>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>
        <lightning:button label="Save" iconPosition="left" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.doSave}"/>
        <lightning:button label="Cancel" iconPosition="right" variant="destructive" onclick="{!c.docancel}"/>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
  
      
    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.acctList }"
                         columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
      
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
   fetchAcc : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchAccHelper(component, event, helper);
    },
      doSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.createAccount');
        action.setParams({
            ac : component.get('v.createAcc')
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(result){
            var getAllValue = component.get('v.createAcc');
            alert(JSON.stringify(getAllValue));
        });
          location.reload();
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    docancel : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.createAcc',"");
    },
})




({
    fetchAccHelper : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'Phone'},
                {label: 'Website', fieldName: 'Website', type: 'url '}
            ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchAccounts");
        action.setParams({
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.acctList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex

```
public class AccountController1
{
     @AuraEnabled
    public static List <Account> fetchAccounts() {
        //Qyery 10 accounts
        List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingState, 
                                    Website, Phone, Industry, Type from Account ];
        //return list of accounts
        return accList;
    }
    
    
 /*    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getPickList(String objName,String fldName) {
        List<String> pkList = new List<String>();Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> allObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> allFlds = allObj.get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pickList = allFlds.get(fldName).getDescribe().getPickListValues();
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry pk : pickList){
            pkList.add(pk.getValue());
        }
        return pkList;
    }   */
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account createAccount(Account ac){
        insert ac;
        return ac;
    }
}
```

Application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:LightningDatatableExample/>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: please add the explanation of the code like what actually you have done the fix the problem faced by OP